# How to show duplicate value on crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Any idea how to repeat same value in crystal report designer instead of increment.

Comment: Could you please provide some more specific information on what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried so far, the results and/or any errors you are getting, and how those results compare to your expected output?

Comment: Thank you McMillan. What I am trying to accomplish was missing actually. After modelling each step on plain paper it really helped me. It was so easy like copy paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using Field Explorer in Visual Studio
2. Expand the Database Fields and find the column name to display.
3. Drag the select column into the designer.
4. Right click on the column and use copy paste feature.